# OpenGL ES 2.0 - Temporary performance drop after rendering texture for the first time

Tags: android, performance, optimization, textures, opengl-es-2.0

Target platform: Android, OpenGL ES 2.0

At the beginning of the scene I upload my texture with `glTexImage2D`, so they are supposed to be right from the beginning available before the actual rendering starts. AFAIK calls to glTexImage2D are very time consuming, because the image data is basically memcopied.

Later on I will use the texture, so I call `glBindTexture` again, to be able to render it. And here comes the funny part: The first time I call `glBindTexture` and actually render the texture the application's framerate drops significantly a couple times but then stabilizes again fully. It seems like the video driver is rearranging memory when the texture is actually used for the first time? Maybe some textures that were previously in RAM are moved to hard disk in order to make space for the texture? That would definietly make sense if there was a mechanism that keeps track when a texture was used the last time and then removes the textures from memory that weren't used for a specific amount of time to make space.

Any ideas on this behavior and maybe a way to force the driver to instantly make space before the actual rendering starts?

Comment: How do you measure there's such a frame rate drop? Also is it on first render this happens only - or "a couple times" as you wrote too?

Comment: It takes like 10-20 seconds until the application runs smooth again. During these 10-20 seconds several frame drops occur. Since I'm using cocos2d-x frame rate measurement should be fine plus you can basically see the stutters.